# Warning while getting content from file, if used "move_uploaded_file()" and "file_get_contents()"

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I´m getting warning with stopping script in PHP, when I use functions in following order:

> **move_uploaded_file()**  *used first*

and after this included next function:

> **file_get_contents()** *used second*

I am getting Warning with message:

> file_get_contents(D:\Programs\WAMP\WAMP_Server\tmp\phpD8E2.tmp):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

But, if I reverse these functions: **file_get_contents()** *first* and then use **move_uploaded_file()** - all is right without error and it works. Where is a problem? My code with errors in below:

```
/* File management variables */
$filename = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"];
$uploadedFile = $_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'];
$uploadedFileType = $_FILES['uploadFile']['type'];
$target_dir = '../uploads/';
$target_dir_file = $target_dir . basename($filename);
$textFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_dir_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

/* First: used  move_uploaded_file() func */
move_uploaded_file($uploadedFile, $target_dir_file);

/* Second: used  file_get_contents() func */
$dbPath = fopen('../database/database.txt', 'a');
$uploadedFile = file_get_contents($uploadedFile);
fwrite($dbPath, $uploadedFile);
fclose($dbPath);
```

If reversed these two functions

```
/* First: used  file_get_contents() func */
$dbPath = fopen('../database/database.txt', 'a');
$uploadedFile = file_get_contents($uploadedFile);
fwrite($dbPath, $uploadedFile);
fclose($dbPath);

/* Second: used  move_uploaded_file() func */
move_uploaded_file($uploadedFile, $target_dir_file);
```

all is right and script works without errors.

Why I´m getting error, when using first **move_uploaded_file()** func and after **file_get_contents()** func, but after reverse it works without errors? How can I fix it without reversing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )` well... moves `$filename` to new `$destination`. Therefore it's no longer available under original path.

Given your first example, you should do:

```
$uploadedFile = file_get_contents($target_dir_file);
```